# How to change attribute of an SVG image in batik while in program?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I want to be able to change the attribute of an SVG document while the program is running by pressing a button (eg turn a black square into blue by changing the fill color). Here is my code:

```
  this.addSVGDocumentLoaderListener(new SVGDocumentLoaderAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void documentLoadingCompleted(SVGDocumentLoaderEvent e) {
      setupSVGDocument();

    }});

}
private SVGDocument doc;
private void setupSVGDocument(){
    doc = this.getSVGDocument();
}
```

Then I want to be able to use the doc to get the element by id and change the attribute of an element when pressing a button like this:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         el = doc.getElementById("statusColor");
        el.setAttributeNS(null, "stop-color", "green");

    }
```

The graphic won't update! Please help!

Comment: Some guesses: Did you use [`.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC)`](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/swing/svg/JSVGComponent.html#setDocumentState%28int%29)? Otherwise, the document might be treated as static and isn't updateable. Is `"stop-color"` actually the attribute you want to change?

Comment: Yes to both questions. If I bring the lines:


 el = doc.getElementById("statusColor");
        el.setAttributeNS(null, "stop-color", "green");

inside the document loaderlistener declaration it works but outside it doesn't. This is killing my time so much. So frustrated. :(