# How can I set a font-family instead of font when using Batik's SVGGraphics2D?

Tags: java, batik

I currently have the following code using Batik's SVGGraphics2D:

```
...
final SVGGraphics2D svgGraphics2D = new SVGGraphics2D(svgGeneratorContext, false);
svgGraphics2D.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(width, height));
svgGraphics2D.setFont(font);
...
```

As a result, if `font` is an available `Font` on the system on which the code is executed, the correct attribute is added to the resulting SVG file.

However, if the font is missing (for instance "Verdana" on a linux box) a default font is used (`font-family:'Dialog'` is added).

Thus, instead of specifying a font, I would like to pass a font-family in order to have `font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif"` in the resulting SVG. How can I achieve this knowing that, if I'm not wrong, the API only accepts `Font` parameters ?

I hope that there's a easier way than using a xslt to transform the xml output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regarding bounty: I'm looking for a general solution to add CSS attributes, not just fonts. The use of SVGGraphics2D is an absolute requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890844/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-an-svg-produced-by-apache-batik and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314035/how-to-change-attribute-of-an-svg-image-in-batik-while-in-program ask essentially the same question but provide no answers. There is a possibility that Batic is well and truly dead and just chills on Apache graveyard, and you should search for another Java+SVG library or may be change your approach completely.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin That is what it looks like. While a real answer would be great, I'm more likely to be accepting some sort of dubious hack that gets the job done, provided it's vaguely reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a (licensed) font file, say as resource, you might do:

```
    InputStream is = SomeClass.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/DejaVu Sans.ttf");
    Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(font);
```

This is a general way to deliver an application with its own font.

Then in the SVG you can embed the exact font for stand-alone svg files.

I wonder that it is not possible to do:

```
font-family="'DejaVu Sans',Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif"
```

as that would be the CSS way.

Comment: What you've described is what the OP already had, a single font. Embedding the font is one workaround to the OP's problem, but I'll award a bounty to a solution that gives more control over CSS if one appears. Thanks!

Comment: @GKFX indeed I have points enough. But I wanted to mention the capability to provide a font with the application, without the operating system having it installed, and for the final svg embedding it. CSS would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `width`, `height`, and Swing component (`label`), the following code will export an SVG document with `viewBox` and `font-family` attributes set on the root `svg` element:

```
final var dom = getDOMImplementation();
final var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
final var doc = dom.createDocument( ns, "svg", null );
final var context = createDefault( doc );
context.setPrecision( 5 );

final var generator = new SVGGraphics2D( context, false );
generator.setSVGCanvasSize( new Dimension( width, height ) );
label.paintComponent( generator );

Element root = generator.getRoot();
final String viewBox = format( "0 0 %d %d", width, height );
root.setAttribute( SVG_VIEW_BOX_ATTRIBUTE, viewBox );
root.setAttribute( "font-family", "Arial" );

try( final var out = new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream( "/tmp/saved.svg" ), UTF_8 ) ) {
  generator.stream( root, out );
}
```

Produces:

```
<svg
  stroke-dasharray="none"
  shape-rendering="auto"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  font-family="Arial"
  width="305"
  text-rendering="auto"
  fill-opacity="1"
  contentScriptType="text/ecmascript"
  color-interpolation="auto"
  color-rendering="auto"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  font-size="12px"
  viewBox="0 0 3 3"
  fill="black"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  stroke="black"
  image-rendering="auto"
  stroke-miterlimit="10"
  zoomAndPan="magnify"
  version="1.0"
  stroke-linecap="square"
  stroke-linejoin="miter"
  contentStyleType="text/css"
  font-style="normal"
  height="311"
  stroke-width="1"
  stroke-dashoffset="0"
  font-weight="normal"
  stroke-opacity="1">
```